# Writing to Kafka from .net core service using Confluent.Kafka

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I have a .net core service that fetches data from a MEMSQL server and returns to the client. However, the queries that are generated at the service needs to be logged to Kafka cluster.

I tried installing Confluent.Kafka package and do the logging, it works fine when running locally. But in the container, the service cannot log and generate the following errors:

```
 warning NU1701: Package 'librdkafka.redist 0.9.5' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
The type initializer for 'Confluent.Kafka.Impl.LibRdKafka' threw an exception.
```

The container is running on a LINUX machine. Basically, I need to figure out a version of Confluent.Kafka that works with .netcore 2.0 and one that does not depend on .NETFramework v4.6.

Answer (score 2):

This warning is harmless - it occurs because librdkafka.redist does not contain any managed code and so nuget can't determine what the target framework is. This warning has been fixed in the upcoming release which we should have out within about a week.

Comment: I tried to suppress the warning by editing csproj as suggested in some forums. That stopped the warning, but the error is generated when the trying to log from the container.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to the latest Confluent Package 0.11.3 fixed the issue. Now the service is able to access Kafka cluster from the docker container.